# How to cast a Interface to a Object in Delphi

Tags: delphi, interface, casting, delphi-2009, pascal

In delphi 2009 I have a reference to a `IInterface` which I want to cast to the underlying `TObject`

Using `TObject(IInterface)` obviously doesn't work in Delphi 2009 (it's supposed to work in Delphi 2010 though)

My searches lead me to [a function that should do the trick](http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2004/07/hack-7-interface-to-object-in-delphi.html), but it doesn't work for me, I get AV's when I try to call methods on the returned object.

<sup>I can't really modify the Classes and I know that this breaks OOP</sup>

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of relying on Delphi's internal object layout you could also have your objects implement another interface which would simply return the object. This, of course, only works if you have access to the source code of the objects to begin with, but you probably shouldn't even use these hacks if you don't have access the source code of the objects.

```
interface 

type
  IGetObject = interface
    function GetObject: TObject;
  end;

  TSomeClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IGetObject)
  public
    function GetObject: TObject;
  end;

implementation

function TSomeClass.GetObject: TObject;
begin
  Result := Self;
end;
```

Comment: I actually ended up using this solution already, but didn't get around to post my own answer yet. Hats off to you!

Answer (score 22):

You are right. Beginning with Delphi 2010, you are able to use the as operator, e.g. via `aObject := aInterface as TObject` or even `aObject  := TObject(aInterface)`.

This `as` operator use a special hidden interface GUID (`ObjCastGUID`) to retrieve the object instance, calling an enhanced version of `TObject.GetInterface`, which does not exist prior to Delphi 2010. See source code of `System.pas` unit to see how it works.

I've published some code working for Delphi 6 up to XE2, [including Delphi 2009](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=4504#p4504).

See http://blog.synopse.info?post/2012/06/13/Retrieve-the-object-instance-from-an-interface

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20200208120346/blog.synopse.info/post/2012/06/13/Retrieve-the-object-instance-from-an-interface

Comment: http://blog.synopse.info?post/2012/06/13/Retrieve-the-object-instance-from-an-interface

Comment: Yeah, but better just edit the link in the answer, because it is 404 as of now

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice alternative when you know the implementing object is a `TComponent` descendant.

You can use the `IInterfaceComponentReference` interface, which is defined up in `Classes` unit:

```
IInterfaceComponentReference = interface
  ['{E28B1858-EC86-4559-8FCD-6B4F824151ED}']
  function GetComponent: TComponent;
end;
```

And then it's declared in `TComponent` (and implemented to return `self`):

```
  TComponent = class(TPersistent, IInterface, IInterfaceComponentReference)
```

So if you **know** the implementing object is a `TComponent` then you can do this:

```
function InterfaceToComponent(const AInterface: IInterface): TComponent;
var
  vReference: IInterfaceComponentReference;
begin
  if Supports(AInterface, IInterfaceComponentReference, vReference) then
    result := vReference.GetComponent
  else
    result := nil;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

In short: you shouldn't or add an interface with a method that returns the pointer for you. Anything else is hackery.

Note that an interface "instance" may be implemented in another language (they are COM compatible) and / or may be a stub for something out of process etc etc.

All in all: an interface instance only agrees to the interface and nothing else, certainly not being implemented as a Delphi TObject instance

Comment: I know it's a hack and it may break things. I asked how not if I should.

Answer (score 2):

Hallvard's hack is very specific to how the Delphi compiler generates code. That has been remarkably stable in the past, but it sounds like they changed something significant in Delphi 2009. I only have 2007 installed here, and in that, Hallvard's code works fine.

Does GetImplementingObject return NIL?

If so, then if you debug and set a break-point on the case statement in the GetImplementingObject routine, what does the value of QueryInterfaceThunk.AddInstruction evaluate to in the debugger?

Comment: It doesn't return nil, it seems like it returns a wrong memory address, because I can see some data of the object but other data is just gibberish

Comment: 2009 introduced a new hidden pointer field (for monitor support). You should adjust the method to account for that.

Comment: Thanks alex, but that method is beyond my expertise in Delphi. Can you elaborate what I should adjust?

Answer (score -2):

```
var
  N, F: NativeInt; // NativeInt is Integer(in delphi 32bit ) 
  S: TObject;
begin
  N := NativeInt(Args[0].AsInterface) - 12; 
  {subtract 12 byte to get object address(in x86 ,1 interface on class) }
  S := TObject(N);    
  writeln(S.ToString);

end;
```

Comment: This may work for some compiler generated code, but not others. It is always better to get the $0C constant from the generated code.