# Casting a delphi interface to its implementation class without modifying the interface

Tags: delphi, interface, delphi-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to cast a Interface to a Object in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138211/how-to-cast-a-interface-to-a-object-in-delphi)

Using Delphi 5; I have an interface that I cannot change for legacy reasons. I am passing (pointers to) that interface all over the place. The implementing class has several new properties - is there a way to force a cast from the interface to the actual implementation?

http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=500 says that this is (newly) implemented in Delphi 2010, which strongly suggest that it wasn't possible before. Is this indeed the case, or is there a way I'm not familiar with? RTTI, maybe?

(I checked, and `if pScore is TOleScore then` is indeed not allowed by the Delphi 5 compiler - here `pScore` is my `pScore: IScore` argument, and `TOleScore` is the implementing class.)

Comment: The difference is that I am forbidden from touching the interface; that restriction did not exist in the other question, AFAICT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The classic take on this is by Hallvard Vassbotn: [Hack #7: Interface to Object](http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2004/07/hack-7-interface-to-object-in-delphi.html)
- More recently Barry Kelly, a Delphi compiler engineer, also provided an implementation: [An ugly alternative to interface to object casting](http://blog.barrkel.com/2011/03/ugly-alternative-to-interface-to-object.html)

I think both approaches should work.

---

Incidentally, does anyone know if Hallvard is still active? I've not come across him in the past few years.

Comment: Yep, Hallvard is still active, he just doesn't blog anymore

Comment: Marked as the answer 'cause I don't want to mark mine :)

Comment: @Marcel Thanks! Out of curiosity, how does the JEDI version differ from Hallvard's?

Answer (score 3):

H/t to my boss, the answer is: use the incredibly useful JEDI library, specifically the [`GetImplementorOfInterface` method](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help%3aGetImplementorOfInterface@IInterface).

Answer (score 2):

i do what the "[possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138211)" question's accepted answer does:

Have the object implement the `IObject` interface:

```
IObject = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{39B4F98D-5CAC-42C5-AF8D-0237C8EFBE4C}']
    function GetSelf: TObject;
end;
```

So it would be:

```
var
   thingy: IThingy;
   o: TOriginalThingy;

begin
   o := (thingy as IObject).GetSelf as TOriginalThingy;
```

---

**Update:** To drive the point home, you can add a new *interface* to an existing object.

Existing object:

```
type
    TOriginalThingy = class(TInterfacedObject, IThingy)
    public
       //IThingy
       procedure DrinkCokeZero; safecall;
       procedure ExcreteCokeZero; cafecall;
    end;
```

Add `IObject` as one of the interfaces it exposes:

```
type
    TOriginalThingy = class(TInterfacedObject, IThingy, IObject)
    public
       //IThingy
       procedure DrinkCokeZero; safecall;
       procedure ExcreteCokeZero; cafecall;

       //IObject - provides a sneaky way to get the object implementing the interface
       function GetSelf: TObject;
    end;

    function TOriginalThingy.GetSelf: TObject;
    begin
       Result := Self;
    end;
```

**Typical usage**:

```
    procedure DiddleMyThingy(Thingy: IThingy);
    var
       o: TThingy;
    begin
       o := (Thingy as IObject).GetSelf as TThingy;

       o.Diddle;
    end;
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like OP can alter the code that implements the interface.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I absolutely cannot touch the interface :(

Comment: @Warren No, this code works on all Delphi versions.

Comment: @David, Marcel: i assume your original **interface** is locked (as interfaces are meant to be). The **object** that you're using will implement **another** completely separate interface. On the other hand if, as David read it, you're not allowed touch any *code* - then that's a different problem.

Comment: Hey look, someone who's a version of Delphi that was written when Jean Chrétien was Prime Minister.

Comment: I misinterpreted your answer too... yes, that would also work. (I can touch the implementing class but not the interface itself.) Unfortunately, I can't mark two questions as the answer :) so just a +1 for you.

Comment: Oh I see.  So we're using the IUnknown capability to basically select a completely different interface, not extend the locked done. VERY nice.

Comment: @Warren P: Exactly! Objects expose themselves to the world through different identities. The best example is a TList that exposes itself as an `IList`, `ICollection` and `IEnumerable`. It's the same TList object, but you present a different "face" to different people for different uses.