# How to convert IStream to TStreamAdapter?

Tags: delphi, com, interface, delphi-7, istream

How to convert IStream to TStreamAdapter on Delphi 7?

On Delphi XE2 I may write:

```
var
  aStream: IStream;
  aStreamAdapter: TStreamAdapter;
begin
  ...
  aStreamAdapter := aStream as TStreamAdapter;
  ...
end;
```

But Delphi 7 writes:

```
Error: Operator not applicable to this operand type
```

Comment: The only possible reason I can think of for wanting to do this is to get access to the `TStreamAdapter.Stream` property, because you previously wrapped a `TStream` object, and now you want it back. If that's what you're doing, then you should have just stored the `TStream` reference somewhere before, and then you wouldn't have to go digging through the `IStream` interface to recover it. The *right* way to get a `TStream` reference from an `IStream` is to create a [`TOleStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.AxCtrls.TOleStream).

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414496  Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138211 Voted to close

Comment: Not duplicate because I have exactly interface and exactly class. There is another good way to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sample code:

```
var
  aFileStream: TFileStream;
  iStr: TStreamAdapter;
  iRes , iRes1, iRes2: Largeint;
  aStreamStat: TStatStg;
  aStreamContent: IStream;
begin
  aFileStream := TFileStream.Create('<...>', fmCreate);
  try
    aStreamContent := <...> as IStream;
    aStreamContent.Seek(0, 0, iRes);
    iStr := TStreamAdapter.Create(aFileStream, soReference);
    aStreamContent.Stat(aStreamStat, 1);
    aStreamContent.CopyTo(iStr, aStreamStat.cbSize , iRes1, iRes2);
  finally
    aFileStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You've misread the question. The post wants to get back to the object that implements the interface, not convert to one. See @David's answer.

Comment: @Ken Ironic considering this answer comes from the person that asked the question! Perhaps this is the solution to Altaveron's actual problem, but it's not the answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: @David: Yeah, didn't catch the poster name. Very strange. ;-) Perhaps Altaveron needs to work on writing better questions?

Comment: This code also plays fast and loose with the `TStreamAdapter` instance that is created. The appropriate approach is to declare `iStr` to be `IStream`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But there is working solution without hacking. iStr is TStreamAdapter with content of IStream. I am not sure if I need to call iStr.Free.

Comment: Read the question that you asked. It demonstrated code that recovers the implementing object from an interface, available in modern Delphi. Then you asked why that code would not work in D7, and how to do the same in D7. My answer addressed the question that you aked. This answers a completely different question. What's more it does it poorly. You simply want to transfer content from an `IStream` to a `TStream`. You have hit upon `TStreamAdapter`, but that's the wrong class. You need `TOLEStream` to solve your real problem.

Comment: Essentially, I feel that you need to understand the difference between the question that you asked, and your underlying problem. You didn't tell us about your underlying problem. Hence my answer and the duplicate close votes.

Answer (score 3):

That code works because of a new feature introduced in D2010, namely the ability to recover a reference to the object that implements an interface. Note though that if the `IStream` is implemented by something other than your Delphi code, then the cast will fail.

If you need to refer to the implementing object in older versions of Delphi then you will need to use one of the various hacks to recover it. For example:

- [Hallvard Vassbotn's classic approach](http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2004/07/hack-7-interface-to-object-in-delphi.html).
- [Barry Kelly's more recent variant](http://blog.barrkel.com/2011/03/ugly-alternative-to-interface-to-object.html?m=1).

However, you should not need to get back to the implementing object. The fact that you do want to is a very strong indication that your design is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The unit AxCtrls has an [TOleStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.AxCtrls.TOleStream) object to do just that.

```
var
  aStream: IStream;
  bStream: TStream;
begin
  bStream := TOleStream.Create(aStream);
  try
    //
  finally
    bStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: No, that's not it. The code in the question recovers the object reference for the object that implements the interface.

Comment: Having said that, the other answer suggests that the intended question was "how do I copy from an IStream to a TStream?" This is the answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Create` method like

```
var StreamAdapter:TStreamAdapter;
begin
  StreamAdapter := TStreamAdapter.Create(aStream);
...
```