# Different behavior of interface between Delphi 7 and Delphi XE and higher

Tags: delphi, interface, delphi-7, delphi-xe

I am having a strange problem of using interface in different versions of Delphi. The following minimized code compiles and runs as expected in Delphi XE and higher but not in Delphi 7. Specificaly, it seems when compiling in Delphi 7, the `function TForm1.Load: IMoleculeSubject;` does not returns the correct result, i.e., the correct reference to the newly created instance. Could you help to comment about the reason and possible workaround? Many thanks!

#### uInterface.pas

```
    unit uInterface;
    
    interface
    
    type
    
      IMoleculeSubject = interface
      ['{BEB4425A-186C-45DF-9DCE-C7175DB0CA90}']
      end;
    
      TMoleculeSubject = class(TInterfacedObject, IMoleculeSubject)
      end;
    
    implementation
    
    end.
```

#### uBusiness.pas

```
    unit uBusiness;
    
    interface
    
    uses
      uInterface;
    
    type
    
      TMoleculeDecorator = class(TMoleculeSubject) 
      private
        FID: Integer;
      public           
        property ID: Integer read FID;
        constructor Create;
      end;
    
    implementation
    
    { TMoleculeDecorator }
    
    constructor TMoleculeDecorator.Create;
    begin
      inherited Create;
    
      FID := Random(100);
    end;
    
    end.
```

#### Unit1.pas

```
    unit Unit1;
    
    interface
    
    uses
      uInterface, uBusiness,
    
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, 
      Forms, Dialogs;
    
    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
      private
        function Load: IMoleculeSubject;
      public
      end;
    
    var
      Form1: TForm1;
    
    implementation
    
    {$R *.dfm}
    
    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    var
      MolSubject: IMoleculeSubject;
    begin
      MolSubject := Load;
    
              // The down-cast is to show the returned result is wrong in Delphi 7!
      Caption := IntToStr(TMoleculeDecorator(MolSubject).ID);
    end;
    
    function TForm1.Load: IMoleculeSubject;   
    var
      MolSubject: IMoleculeSubject;
    begin
      MolSubject := TMoleculeDecorator.Create;
      Result := MolSubject;
    end;
    
    end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Load` function works perfectly well in all versions of Delphi. The problem is your cast, which is what is known as an *unsafe typecast*. An unsafe typecast from an interface reference to an object has ill-defined behaviour in older versions of Delphi. However, the behaviour is well-defined in modern Delphi. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Interface_References#Interface_Typecasts) says more.

So, the basic problem is that your expectations for the behaviour are not compatible with the Delphi 7 version of the language.

If you get the interface to return the ID you will find that the interface you are creating is as expected.

```
program InterfaceDemo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes;

type
  IMyIntf = interface
    function GetID: Integer;
  end;

  TImplementingObject = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyIntf)
  private
    FID: Integer;
    function GetID: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

{ TImplementingObject }

constructor TImplementingObject.Create;
begin
  FID := Random(100);
  Writeln(FID);
end;

function TImplementingObject.GetID: Integer;
begin
  Result := FID;
end;

var
  MyIntf: IMyIntf;

begin
  Randomize;
  MyIntf := TImplementingObject.Create;
  Writeln(MyIntf.GetID);
  Readln;
end.
```

It's rather unusual to ask for the implementing object from an interface. To do so suggests that there is a problem with your design. Should you really need to do so there are a few options:

- In modern Delphi you can use the type-safe case with the `as` operator.
- In older Delphi versions there are hacks that retrieve the implementing object: [Casting a delphi interface to its implementation class without modifying the interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414496/casting-a-delphi-interface-to-its-implementation-class-without-modifying-the-int?lq=1)
- You could add a function to the interface that returns the implementing object.

The latter option works in all versions of Delphi and does so without resorting to subterfuge.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions! However, could you help to comment further regarding `design`? It seems that one has to duplicate the declarations of the implementing object in the interface to eliminate the need of using the implementing object. I thought it is tedious and error-prone to duplicate declarations?

Comment: What are your motivations for using interfaces then? You appear to be wanting to create interfaces with no methods. In which case, what purpose do they serve? It's hard to offer advice without understanding your motivations. One normally creates interfaces that contain method declarations!

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I rushed myself an "observer framework" using `XPObserver` and `XPInterfacedObject` from `dunit`. Because interfaces are used in these two units, I declared child interfaces to learn. I didn't understand thoroughly these two units (and `mghie`'s answer of my SO question 11105361). Therefore, it puzzled me whether to put method declarations in the subject interface, or to just use the subject as "subject" and cast it to specific object to use. I have to learn further.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - 'interfaces with no methods' (i.e. IUnknown as Delphi concerned) can be used to implement lifetime memory management for user-defined types.

Comment: @Serg I was trying not to jump to any conclusions.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Could you help to comment that in the "observer pattern", whether one should declare all properties and methods in the subject interface and let the observers only call the subject interface, or one should declare the properties and methods in the implementing objects and let the observers down-cast to the specific business object?

Comment: The typical implementation of `ISubject` has just three methods, `Attach`, `Detach` and `Notify`. Why do you want to add more than that?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thank you for your further comments! In this respect, is it true that there has to be down-cast from `ISubject` interface to business data object in the `observers`? Or that `ISubject` should not have inheritance relationship with the business data object? Could you help to comment?

Comment: I don't see why you need any casting at all here. There are lots of examples of Delphi implementations of this pattern on the web. And they don't do any casting from interface to object. I'd look at these examples to see how they do it.

Answer (score 5):

Casting interfaces to objects is available since Delphi 2010. Where are workarounds for older Delphi versions, see for example [How to cast a Interface to a Object in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138211/how-to-cast-a-interface-to-a-object-in-delphi)